# Can the interface types otnOtu, otnOdu and opticalChannel have metrics such as ifInDiscards, ifOutDiscards?

Tags: ethernet

In my understanding, the metrics "ifInDiscards", "ifOutDiscards", "ifOutErrors", "ifInErrors", "ifOutUcastPkts", "ifInUcastPkts".,,,etc are basically related to the interfaceType **ethernetCsmacd**. 
Can the interfaceTypes **otnOtu**, **otnOdu** and **opticalChannel** have the above mentioned metrics?

Comment: Potentially all interfaces have discard, error and packet counters - care to share the device type/make/model with us?

Comment: Thank you @Zac67 for the response. The device is a transponder(Fujitsu 1finity T300)